# Como pegar texto específico de um arquivo txt em C#?

Tags: c#, txt

Sou leigo, ainda dando os primeiros passos na programação e no C# e estou com dificuldades em resolver um problema.

Gostaria de buscar uma informação específica em um arquivo txt com as seguintes linhas:

```
Nodal force point

15  25  30

20  35  13

25  85  25


Nodal Moment point

23  58  6

6   4   5   

3   2   1

Nodal displacements point

25  1   5

2   5   4

6   4   5
```

Bom, preciso identificar no txt o "**Nodal Moment point**" e armazenar o **segundo valor da segunda linha** (Nesse caso, o valor **4**).

Obs: Não necessariamente será o 4, uma vez que são valores gerados aleatoriamente. Ah, o arquivo sempre irá seguir esse padrão (Cada título terá 3 linhas de dados, sempre vai ter uma linha em branco e as colunas são separadas por 2 espaços)

Estou usando o seguinte código para localizar a parte do arquivo que contém o "Nodal Moment point":

```
var valor = File.ReadAllLines("NomeDoArquivo.txt")
                .Where(l=>l.StartsWith("Nodal Moment"))
```

No entanto, não sei como buscar o segundo valor da segunda linha e armazenar na variável.

**Agradeço desde já a ajuda de vocês.**

Comment: Não tem como te ajudar sem saber mais detalhes do formato do arquivo. Cada título terá 3 linhas de dados? Depois do título sempre vai ter uma linha em branco (no último título tem 2)? As colunas sempre serão separadas por 2 espaços?

Comment: Tem razão. Cada título terá 3 linhas de dados, sempre vai ter uma linha em branco e as colunas são separadas por 2 espaços. Sempre seguindo esse padrão.

Comment: Vou corrigir a postagem. Obrigado pelo comentário!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O algoritmo é simples:

- `File.ReadAllLines("file.txt")`: Leia o arquivo de texto.
- `SkipWhile(l => l != "Nodal Moment point")`: Descarte todas as linhas até encontrar a string `"Nodal Moment point"`.
- `Except(new string[]{""})`: Remova todas as linhas vazias.
- `Skip(1)`: Descarte a linha que contem a string `"Nodal Moment point"`.
- `TakeWhile(l => Char.IsNumber(l[0]))`: Apanhe as linhas enquanto o primeiro caractere for numérico e descarte todas as linhas inclusive e após encontrar a primeira linha cujo primeiro caractere não for numérico.
- `Select((l,_) => l.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))`: Para as linhas remanescentes as exploda nos espaços em arrays de string descartando as strings vazias.
- `ToArray()`: Junte o resultado num array organizado em linha por colunas.

> <sup>Lembrando que arrays em *C#* começam no índice 0.
>
> Então caso queira o terceiro elemento da primeira linha será `data[0][2]`.</sup>

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    var data = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt")       
       .SkipWhile(l => l != "Nodal Moment point")
       .Except(new string[]{""})
       .Skip(1)
       .TakeWhile(l => Char.IsNumber(l[0]))
       .Select((l,_) => l.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
       .ToArray();
    Console.WriteLine(data[1][1]);    //4
  }
}
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/NodalMomentpoint#main.cs)</sup>

**Visualização do que faz cada função faz:**

- `File.ReadAllLines("file.txt")`

```
Nodal force point

15  25  30

20  35  13

25  85  25


Nodal Moment point

23  58  6

6   4   5   

3   2   1

Nodal displacements point

25  1   5

2   5   4

6   4   5
```

- `SkipWhile(l => l != "Nodal Moment point")`

```
Nodal Moment point

23  58  6

6   4   5   

3   2   1

Nodal displacements point

25  1   5

2   5   4

6   4   5
```

- `Except(new string[]{""})`

```
Nodal Moment point
23  58  6
6   4   5
3   2   1
Nodal displacements point
25  1   5
2   5   4
6   4   5
```

- `Skip(1)`

```
23  58  6
6   4   5
3   2   1
Nodal displacements point
25  1   5
2   5   4
6   4   5
```

- `TakeWhile(l => Char.IsNumber(l[0]))`

```
23  58  6
6   4   5
3   2   1
```

- `Select((l,_) => l.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))`

```
Array<String>["23","58","6"]
Array<String>["6","4","5"]
Array<String>["3","2","1"]
```

- `ToArray();`

```
data = [["23","58","6"], ["6","4","5"], ["3","2","1"]]
```

**Referências:**

- [`File.ReadAllLines()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=net-5.0)
- [`Enumerable.SkipWhile()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skipwhile?view=net-5.0)
- [`Enumerable.Except()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-5.0)
- [`Enumerable.Skip()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?view=net-5.0)
- [`Enumerable.TakeWhile()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile?view=net-5.0)
- [`Enumerable.Select()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-5.0)
- [`Enumerable.ToArray()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray?view=net-5.0)
- [`Char.IsNumber()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.char.isnumber?view=net-5.0)
- [`String.Split()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0)
- [`System.Linq`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.linq?view=net-5.0)
- [`System.IO`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.io?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Explicação fantástica. Agradeço demais sua ajuda. Farei o teste e volto para dar o feedback. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string arquivo = @"C:\temp\teste.txt";

        if(File.Exists(arquivo))
        {
                try
                {
                    string[] listTxt = File.ReadAllLines(arquivo);
                    var strList = listTxt[13];
                    var values = strList.Split("  ");
                    var result = values[1];
                }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, vai ajudar bastante!